# Firestore: How to set DocumentListenOptions in JavaScript?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

While using **Firebase-Firestore** database, I need to set some configuration parameters accesible via **DocumentListenOptions** using the Web javascript sdk.
I've found many examples of this in java and other languages, but it seems there is no documentation for JavaScript.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DocumentListenOptions you're pointing to is a part of the Android API.

In the web API there's no special type for this: just pass { includeMetadataChanges: true } as options to the onSnapshot method, as described here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#onSnapshot

Cheers,
-Gil